# VB.NET: I have a DataTable I want to Display, is there anyway to do this without binding it to a datagrid or gridview?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, pagination

I have a datatable and am currently binding it to a datagrid, however, when i go to enable paginating it is very messy.  Is there a more malleable method for displaying and paginating aside from using a gridview or datagrid???

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is messy? Otherwise anything suggested could also potentially be something that you may consider messy!!

Comment: Haha, yes you are definitely right.  Currently, when I bind the datatable to the datagrid and enable pagination, the page numbers are spaced so far apart that it makes the grid itself much wider.  This is a problem for me because I have to display this data in a paginated sortable manner in a 400px wide div

Comment: Have you tried changing the pagerstyle mode? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.pagerstyle%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Not yet, I will look at this and attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can configure the DataGridView to automatically update the column width, or you can do call this function after changing/loading the data, binded to the DataGridView.

(2) Also consider using .AutoSizeColumnsMode = [..].Fill and change some of the FillWeights.

Read up here:

- [MSDN: Sizing Options in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b2wakt.aspx)
- [MSDN: Column Fill Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171605%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)